# C# delegate configuration Action<T> on a generically type collection of a derived class

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, polymorphism

I'm struggling to provide a delegate configuration action to a collection whose type is of an abstract base class.

The derived classes are registered within the collection, and at run time, the correct base class is selected, initialized, and what I am hoping is that I can pass an action to configure the instance outside of the common parameter passed in from the `CreateInstance` call.

The below example is pretty close to what I am trying to achieve. The wheels fall off the bus in the `RegisterDefinition` method where I'm trying to assign the `Action<T>` to the `FooDefinition<T>` object. I've tried various approaches, including using an interface instead and or in conjunction with the abstract class, and a `Func` but falling short of getting it wired correctly.

For context, the `Bar` class represents a processor of sorts, that will receive something coming into it, and pass it on to the corresponding `FooBase` class. The derived classes will know what to do with that specific something but might share a resource (like a blocking queue). `FooOne`might share a blocking queue with `FooTwo`, but not `FooThree`- thus the need to configure them when they are registered.

```cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bar = new Bar();

            // Register Foos
            bar.RegisterDefinition<FooOne>("1");
            bar.RegisterDefinition<FooTwo>("2", a => a.fooTwoResource = "McFoo");
            bar.RegisterDefinition<FooThree>("3", a => {
                a.fooThreeResource_1 = "McFoo";
                a.fooThreeResource_2 = "McBar";
            });

            // Foo user selection
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want FooOne(1), or FooTwo(2), or FooTwo(3)");
            var fooSelection = Console.ReadLine();
            
            if (fooSelection == "1" || fooSelection == "2" || fooSelection == "3")
            {
                bar.RunFoo(fooSelection);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid foo, no bar for you!");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        private List<FooDefinition<FooBase>> fooDefinitions;

        public Bar()
        {
            fooDefinitions = new List<FooDefinition<FooBase>>();
        }

        public void RegisterDefinition<T>(string name) where T : FooBase
        {
            RegisterDefinition<T>(name, null);
        }

        public void RegisterDefinition<T>(string name, Action<T> configAction) where T : FooBase
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) throw new ArgumentException("You must name the foo");
            if (fooDefinitions.Any(p => p.Name == name)) throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to duplicate foo");

            fooDefinitions.Add(
                new FooDefinition<FooBase>()
                {
                    Name = name,
                    DerivedFoo = typeof(T),
                    //ConfigAction = configAction // Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Action<T>' to 'System.Action<InitializationAction<FooBase>>'.
                    //ConfigAction = (Action<FooBase>)configAction // Compiles, but results in an InvalidCastException when run. 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Action`1[InitializationAction.FooTwo]' to type 'System.Action`1[InitializationAction.FooBase]'.'
                });
        }

        public void RunFoo(string fooName)
        {
            var fooDefinition = fooDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == fooName);
            if (fooDefinition == null) return;

            // Create a new instance of the class, and pass in a common resource (in this example, a string).
            var fooInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(fooDefinition.DerivedFoo, "foo") as FooBase;

            // Run an action that would set any additional properties as necessary
            fooDefinition.ConfigAction?.Invoke(fooInstance);

            fooInstance.Bared();
        }
    }

    public class FooDefinition<T> where T : FooBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Type DerivedFoo { get; set; }
        public Action<T> ConfigAction { get; set; }
    }

    // I tried an interface, it did not work.
    //public interface IFoo
    //{
    //    string fooString { get; }
    //    void Go();
    //}

    //public abstract class FooBase : IFoo
    public abstract class FooBase
    {
        public string fooString { get; private set; }

        public FooBase(string fooString)
        {
            this.fooString = fooString;
        }

        public abstract void Bared();
    }

    public class FooOne : FooBase
    {
        public FooOne(string fooString) : base(fooString) { }

        public override void Bared()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"DerivedFoo: {nameof(FooOne)}: {fooString}");
        }
    }

    public class FooTwo : FooBase
    {
        public string fooTwoResource { get; set; }

        public FooTwo(string fooString) : base(fooString) { }

        public override void Bared()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"DerivedFoo: {nameof(FooTwo)}: {fooString} {fooTwoResource}");
        }
    }

    public class FooThree : FooBase
    {
        public string fooThreeResource_1 { get; set; }
        public string fooThreeResource_2 { get; set; }

        public FooThree(string fooString) : base(fooString){ }

        public override void Bared()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"DerivedFoo: {nameof(FooThree)}: {fooString} {fooThreeResource_1} {fooThreeResource_2}");
        }
    }
```

While I realize that I could switch on the Type when creating the instance, that would couple the `Bar` class with the implementation requirements of each derived ```FooBase`` class, and doesn't seem as clean of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [MinIoC](https://github.com/microsoft/MinIoC) for DI and then just resolved the required services within the derived class constructor.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bar = new Bar();

            // Register Services
            bar.Container.Register<FooService>();

            // Register Foos
            bar.RegisterFoo<FooOne>("1");
            bar.RegisterFoo<FooTwo>("2");

            // Foo user selection
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want FooOne(1), or FooTwo(2)");
            var fooSelection = Console.ReadLine();
            
            if (fooSelection == "1" || fooSelection == "2")
            {
                bar.RunFoo(fooSelection);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid foo, no bar for you!");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        private Dictionary<string, Type> registeredFoos;
        public Container Container { get; private set; } 

        public Bar()
        {
            Container = new Container();
            registeredFoos = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
        }

        public void RegisterFoo<T>(string name) where T : FooBase
        {
            registeredFoos.Add(name, typeof(T));
        }

        public void RunFoo(string fooName)
        {
            if (registeredFoos.TryGetValue(fooName, out var fooType))
            {
                var fooInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(fooType, new object[] { "foo", Container }) as FooBase;
                fooInstance?.Bared();
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class FooBase
    {
        protected Container _container;

        public string fooString { get; private set; }

        public FooBase(string fooString, Container container)
        {
            this.fooString = fooString;
            _container = container;
        }

        public abstract void Bared();
    }

    public class FooOne : FooBase
    {
        public FooOne(string fooString, Container serviceContainer) : base(fooString, serviceContainer) { }

        public override void Bared()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"DerivedFoo: {nameof(FooOne)}: {fooString}");
        }
    }

    public class FooTwo : FooBase
    {
        private readonly FooService fooService;

        public FooTwo(string fooString, Container container) : base(fooString, container) 
        {
            fooService = container.Resolve<FooService>();
        }

        public override void Bared()
        {
            var something = fooService.GetSomething();

            Console.WriteLine($"DerivedFoo: {nameof(FooTwo)}: {fooString} {something}");
        }
    }

    public class FooService
    {
        public string GetSomething()
        {
            return "something";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The core issue seems to be about how to convert the `Action<T>` to a `Action<FooBase>`. You must forego type safety and cast the parameter:

```
ConfigAction = x => configAction?.Invoke((T)x)
```

In addition, I don't think there is any point in `FooDefinition` should be generic at all. You don't get any more type-safe this way, because you seem to have already thrown type-safety out of the window: there is no compile time check that `DerivedFoo` will be `typeof(T)`, is there? Plus, you are only using `FooDefinition<FooBase>` and not `FooDefinition<AnythingElse>`, so `FooDefinition` could just be:

```
public class FooDefinition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type DerivedFoo { get; set; }
    public Action<FooBase> ConfigAction { get; set; }
}
```

And here's `Bar` for completeness:

```
public class Bar
{
    // note the change in type
    private List<FooDefinition> fooDefinitions;

    public Bar()
    {
        fooDefinitions = new List<FooDefinition>();
    }

    public void RegisterDefinition<T>(string name) where T : FooBase
    {
        RegisterDefinition<T>(name, null);
    }

    public void RegisterDefinition<T>(string name, Action<T> configAction) where T : FooBase
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) throw new ArgumentException("You must name the foo");
        if (fooDefinitions.Any(p => p.Name == name)) throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to duplicate foo");

        fooDefinitions.Add(
            new FooDefinition()
            {
                Name = name,
                DerivedFoo = typeof(T),
                ConfigAction = x => configAction?.Invoke((T)x)
            });
    }

    public void RunFoo(string fooName)
    {
        var fooDefinition = fooDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == fooName);
        if (fooDefinition == null) return;

        // Create a new instance of the class, and pass in a common resource (in this example, a string).
        var fooInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(fooDefinition.DerivedFoo, "foo") as FooBase;

        // Run an action that would set any additional properties as necessary
        fooDefinition.ConfigAction?.Invoke(fooInstance);

        fooInstance.Bared();
    }
}
```